# Eclipse не видит Java3D (Linux)

Tags: java, linux, eclipse

Скачал с репозитория *libjava3d-java*. Но эклипс не видит библиотеку. Может стоит указать путь вручную, только вот я не знаю куда она скачалась

Comment: Может я что-то путаю, но ее ведь забросили, нет? Почему не воспользоватся более актуальными вещами как lwjgl или libGDX (второе активно используют в мобильных играх)?

Comment: @RiĥardBrugekĥaim lwjgl мне не подходит, по крайней мере я не смог найти в интернете то, что надо мне (мне нужно вывести окно 3d вида, т.н. вьюпорт в Jpanel) - собираюсь сделать свой 3d редактор с изюминкой. А libgdx сделан на lwjgl для мобильных девайсов, тоже не подойдет

Comment: Первые 2 ссылки в Google http://forum.lwjgl.org/index.php?topic=4275.0 и http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26199534/how-to-attach-opengl-display-to-a-jframe-and-dispose-of-it-properly. Вобще что java3d что Swing сейчас если и развиваются, то на голом энтузиазме, Oracle на них давно забил.